# Eclipse IDE could not find android.jar

Tags: android, eclipse

Good day. 
I did offline installation of Android SDK and eclipse for Java EE developers. 
Now I installed the ADT (offline also) into the eclipse and it worked fine. 
But when I try setting the SDK location via

> Windows > preferences

I get an error: 
**Could not find C:\Users\KEN\AppData\Local\Android\andoird-sdk\android.jar**

How do I fix this. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't think that's the actual error. There is no **andoird-sdk** folder. And do you not know how to search your drive to find a file? I have the SDK installed, and there is nothing related to Android in **APPDATA\Local**, so why are you telling Eclipse to look there for it?

Comment: I've fixed the problem. I had to go through the normal process (i.e online installation). And yes, that's the path. It doesn't throw any error and it accepts that path. It works fine now